# Email and Domain Name at one host; website at another

Tags: dns, shared-hosting, email-accounts

I'm having a strange issue and tech support at either hosting company is not helpful. So thought I'd try here.

Issue: Cannot forward an email account hosted on Namecheap to an email account hosted at GoDaddy where the domain at GoDaddy has its website hostead at Namecheap.

Error message: (Warning: “email@domain1.example” does not refer to a valid local email account or alias. The system will not create a forwarder, because it already sends that email to the default address.)

Details:

`Domain1.example` - The domain name and email are hosted at GoDaddy, the website is hosted at Namecheap.

- DNS records are set with MX and mail records pointing to GoDaddy email services.
- the email works fine for sending and receiving. No problems with that.
- Website - the A record in the DNS at GoDaddy, is pointed to the Namecheap server.
- the website works fine.

`Domain2.example` - The domain name, email, website are all at Namecheap. they work fine.

Here is where the problem comes in. I want to forward an email from `domain2.example` (e.g. `email@domain2.example` - the one at Namecheap) to an email address at `domain1.example` (the one where just the email and DNS are at GoDaddy). Because the website for `domain1.example` is hosted at Namecheap, it seems to be confused about the email address and thinks it should be at Namecheap, but it is not. (at least this is what I think the problem is). So when I try to add a forwarder to forward `email@domain2.example` to `email@domain1.example` I get the error message listed above.

Other item that may or may not help for hosting `domain1.example` website at Namecheap I added it via cPanel as an "add-on domain" and the A record in the DNS at GoDaddy points to the Namecheap IP address. I don't know if there is some other way I was supposed to add the domain name at Namecheap for it to recognize it for the website.

Forwarding works fine to forward `email@domain2.example` to any other domain email address. The problem seems to be that it thinks the email address should be at Namecheap but it is at GoDaddy.

Hopefully I've included everything clearly. Any insights on how to get the email forwarding to work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "The problem seems to be that it thinks the email address should be at Namecheap but it is at Godaddy." If so, isn't that something only Namecheap can fix on their end? Otherwise your only other option is for that domain to also not use Namecheap for email and find a place where you can configure it as you need.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickMevzek. Yes, I can move the website to another hosting provider, but the whole thing has happened because I am trying to consolidate some of my websites to Namecheap.  I was hoping this would be something I can fix through cPanel - I'll try replicating all the DNS records from GoDaddy into the DNS on Namecheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an email routing issue.

Check the cpanel "email routing" setting at Namecheap and make sure that domain1.example is set to `remote`.

Comment: Thank you. That was it! it was set to automatic. Thank you!